# Python math operation on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

Data from json is in df and am trying to ouput to a csv.
I am trying to multiply dataframe column with a fixed value and having issues how data is displayed

I have used the following but the data is still not how i want to display

```py
df_entry['Hours'] = df_entry['Hours'].multiply(2)
df_entry['Hours'] = df_entry['Hours'] * 2
```

Input

```
ID, name,hrs
100,AB,37.5
```

Expected

```
ID, name,hrs
100,AB,75.0
```

What I am getting

```
ID, name,hrs
100,AB,37.537.5
```

Comment: It appears "Hours" is a string column, so try converting it to numeric and multiplying using, `pd.to_numeric(df_entry['Hours'], errors='coerce') * 2`

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the dtype of the column is str. You need to convert it to float before multiplication.

```
df_entry['Hours'] = df_entry['Hours'].astype(float) * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply function.

```
df_entry['Hours'] = df_entry['Hours'].apply(lambda x: float(int(x))*2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and got the identical display as what i had earlier

Comment: I updated my answer